# Where is syslog output stored on Cygwin?

Tags: logging, cygwin, syslog, syslog-ng

I am completely new to the UNIX environment. I see that on most Linux implementations syslog logs can be found at `/var/log/syslog`. On Cygwin I am invoking a `syslog()` call in my C source file using `syslog.h`. The file compiles and executes correctly, but I cannot find any indication of where the log is stored. My `/var/log` directory doesn't even contain a `/syslog` folder.

Even from the terminal, the `logger` user command seems to execute just fine but again I can't find the log.

When I've searched on Google for this issue, I get vague unrelated links to the `syslog-ng` packages. I am not sure if this package is at all related to the issue at hand. I've downloaded it from the Cygwin installer, but it did not help.

For the UNIX specific questions that I've read on StackOverflow, many answers direct users to `etc/syslog.conf`, but that does not exist either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `/usr/bin/syslog-ng-config` to configure the service

The configuration will go in `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. For other newcomers, I also had to install cygrunsrv, and run the terminal as a windows administrator. Once those two things were done, I was able to follow the advice from @matzeri. I also had to use `chmod -R 775` on the `var/log/` directory to be able to open the messages log.